# How to pass arguments by reference to robot framework keywords?

Tags: pass-by-reference, robotframework, keyword-argument

I have a keyword in robot framework; it takes an argument, performs some process on it and returns it after all:

```
My Keyword Name
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    # Some process on ${arg}
    [Return]       ${arg}
```

So it would be the usage:

```
${x} =    My Keyword Name    ${x}
```

Which implies that I gave the old value of `${x}` to the keyword and it returned me the new value of it.

I want to make a call by reference on `My Keyword Name`, so I don't need to use an assignment for setting new value for `${x}`. I have read the [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) and [UserGuide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html),
but there was no line about this subject. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `${x}` is a mutable type such as a list or dictionary, you can pass the object itself. If it represents a scalar value such as a string or int, you can't do what you want.  Your only choice is to return the new value and re-assign it to the original variable.

Comment: I think you are right. I explored a lot and found nothing.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar Python's mutable types are in fact changeable by keywords - check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you initialize the variable as

```
My Keyword Name
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    ${arg} =    Set Variable    56
    [Return]       ${arg}

Test
    Log To Console  \n\nin Test
    ${x} =  Set Variable    0
    ${x} =    My Keyword Name    ${x}
    Log To Console  ${x}
```

**Or**

Can you explore whether you can make use of **Set Global Variable** or **Set Test Variable**?

Comment: The code you provided is identical to mine. BTW, I don't wanna make it global, I just want to eliminate redundant use of variable.

Answer (score 2):

It actually comes down to mutable/immutable variables in python, and how they are passed to functions.

Details here [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/3446126), but in RF context it boils down to - you can change lists and dictionaries, and not strings and numbers (int, float). Example:

```
A testcase
    Log To Console      \n
    ${var}=     Create List   member1
    Log To Console      ${var}

    Mutate The List     ${var}
    Log To Console      ${var}

*** Keywords ***
Mutate The List
    [Arguments]     ${lst}
    Append To List      ${lst}    new one
```

The output when ran would be:

```
==============================================================================
A testcase                                                            

['member1']
['member1', 'new one']
| PASS |
```

, e.g. the variable defined in the case got changed by a keyword. The same can be done with dictionaries.

If you reassign the variable in the function though, it will not change; e.g. with a keyword like this:

```
Mutate The Dict
    [Arguments]     ${lst}
    ${lst}=     Create List    fsf
    Append To List      ${lst}    bogus
```

, the original variable `${var}` will not be changed.
Why so? In short, in python variables are just identifiers ("names") to memory addresses; when you assign `${lst}` to a new list, the variable now points to a new address in the memory, and further interactions don't change the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd spent some time before i got the solution!

```
* Variables
${someVar}    initial value

* Test Cases
[Check reference]
    Set this          \${someVar}    new value
    Should Be Equal    ${someVar}    new value

* Keywords
Set this
[Arguments]          ${varName}    ${value}
Set Test Variable    ${varName}    ${value}
```

The point is in the magic "\" char :)

Answer (score -1):

Welp I just ran into the same issue, as I was using a Run Keyword If statement in a For Loop. Knowing that if I used a keyword that returns a value, robot framework freaks out.

So I just thought of this as a potential solution. It'll use my example. It does have redundancy, but thats because you just have to in this case.

```
***Keywords***
| Increment | [Arguments] | ${var} |
| | ${var} | Evaluate | ${var} + 1 |
| | Set Test Variable | ${var} | ${var} |
```

Usage:

```
| Increment | ${idx} |
| Set Test Variable | ${idx} | ${var}
```

Now I'm not saying this is the best solution, but if you run into the scenario that you have to return a value to a variable with a keyword, and you're inside a "Run Keyword If", this should allow you to circumvent the issue. I don't really like it that much, but it gets the job done.